# How to use Compass through JRuby, for embedding in my soft'?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, compass-sass

I've to "compile" compass files dynamically in my java soft'. So, following explications found on stackoverflow, I've done these steps :

- Get JRuby (1.7.3), configure PATH to jruby.jar and binaries (gem, rake ...) and learn to launch ruby script from Java
- Get compass and dependancies gems into a local directory, using following command line

  ```
  gem install -i ./compass compass
  ```

  => So I get a directory `./compass/` containing `bin, cache,doc, gems & specifications` directories.
- Put gems in a jar using following command line (think to use a jar name which is not the same as the gems, to avoid JRuby "require" the jar instead of the gems)

  ```
  jar cf compass-lib.jar -C compass .
  ```
- Write a test script `test.rb` in local directory to test my jar. It contains :

  ```
  require 'compass'

  Compass.add_configuration(
      {
          :project_path => '.',
          :sass_path => 'styles/scss',
          :css_path => 'styles/css'
      },
      'custom' # A name for the configuration, can be anything you want
  )
  Compass.compiler.compile('test.scss', 'test.css')
  ```
- Execute this script with JRuby, with following command line :

  ```
  jruby -I . -rcompass-lib.jar test.rb
  ```
- And get this error ...

  ```
  Unable to load Sass. Please install it with one of the following commands:
    gem install sass --pre
  LoadError: no such file to load -- jar:file:C:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/jruby.jar!/gems/s
  ass-3.2.8/lib/sass/../sass
    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
    require at c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
     (root) at jar:file:C:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/jruby.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass/ver
  sion.rb:5
    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
     (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
    require at c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
     (root) at jar:file:C:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/jruby.jar!/gems/sass-3.2.8/lib/sass.rb:
  9
     (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
    require at c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60
     (root) at jar:file:C:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/jruby.jar!/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/comp
  ass/dependencies.rb:6
       each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
     (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
    require at c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
     (root) at test.rb:1
  ```

An idea of the problem and, maybe, of solution ? ;) Thanks by advance.

**[UPDATE #1]**

After Jörg W Mittag obvious suggestion, the error disapear. Thanks ;) Now, it just don't find the scss file, so it's a "normal problem" ;)

**[UPDATE #2]**

Having used compass with success in IRB, it's time to transpose the test through Java. So, I wrote some lines in Java to execute my ruby script, using only absolute path to avoid problems in a first time.

```
InputStream myFile = ISRessources.getFile("C:/Path/To/My/test.rb");
new ScriptingContainer().runScriptlet(myFile, "test.rb");
```

But ... how to "load" my `compass-lib.jar` ? What's the equivalent of the `-r` in JRuby ? I've tried to includ gems into jruby.jar, to add compass-lib.jar in externals jars in java build path, but both don't work, I still have :

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- compass
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
   (root) at test.rb:1
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

> Unable to load Sass. Please install it with one of the following commands:
>
> ```
> gem install sass --pre
> ```

Comment: Install compass with gem, automatically install sass. That's mean compass install "badly" sass ? It seems strange ... But I'll try :)

Comment: I thought you wanted to load your gems from a `.jar`? Then, it's irrelevant whether the gem is installed or not, what's relevant is whether you packaged it into the `.jar`.

Comment: When I run `gem install -i ./compass compass`, it install compass, but also sass-3.2.8 into the ./compass directory.
Installing sass with pre, it add sass-3.3.0.alpha.133 into the directory (and that's work !). So I see that as a compass install fail, but maybe it's an other problem ?